# Converting hex to bytes using the win32 API wide string - matasano challenge #2

Tags: windows, winapi, xor, widechar

I've started doing the matasano challenges and decided to do it with just the C PL and the win32 API.

I want to do it this way since I want to get very familiar with the win32 API and the obfuscation/encryption techniques malware authors would use.

I've noticed that the second challenge will require me to use the wide string version of the CryptStringToBinary (=CryptStringToBinaryW) since I can't properly decode the first hex string properly (only 3 characters properly decoded as opposed to the 18 characters in the second given hex string).

Here's the link to the challenge:
https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/2

I've been really struggling for the past few hours trying to convert this to the wide string version but I could not get it to work at all, here's my current code (which works great for the ANSI):

```
LPSTR ToBinary(BYTE* test, LPSTR buffer, DWORD amount) {
if (CryptStringToBinaryA(test, strlen(test), CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW, NULL, &amount, NULL, NULL))
{
    buffer = malloc(amount + 1);
    memset(buffer, 0, amount + 1);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed, error: %lu", GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }
    if (CryptStringToBinaryA(test, strlen(test), CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW, buffer, &amount, NULL, NULL))
    {
        printf("%s \n", buffer);
    }
}
else
    printf("failed, error: %lu", GetLastError());

return buffer;


 }


int main(void)
{
    BYTE * test = "1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c";
    LPSTR first = NULL;
    DWORD amount = 0;
    first = ToBinary(test, first, amount);


    LPSTR buffer2 = NULL;
    BYTE* test2 = "686974207468652062756c6c277320657965";
    amount = 0;
    LPSTR second = NULL;
    second = ToBinary(test2, second, amount);



    return 0;
}
```

**My question is:**

How do I convert this into the wide string version?

I've tried replacing all the LPSTR with LPWSTR, strlen to wsclen and use the "reinterpret casting" to convert from LPWSTR to BYTE* as required by the winAPI documentation. (like this: foo = (BYTE*)test; when test is of type LPCWSTR).

but after all my changes, my program doesn't work anymore.

I'm quite the beginner in C programming and I'm probably missing the correct "attitude" for these kind of conversion problems, I hope this is not a direct duplicate to another question.

**Edit:**

I've tried this code but when I check the strlen of the first value, it returns a length of 3 rather than 18 on the second hex string:

length is: 3

hit the bull's eye

length is: 18

---

Here's the code I tried:

```
BYTE* ToBinary(LPCWSTR test, BYTE* buffer, DWORD amount) {
    if (CryptStringToBinaryW(test, wcslen(test), CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW, NULL, &amount, NULL, NULL))
    {
        buffer = malloc(amount + 1);
        memset(buffer, 0, amount + 1);
        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            printf("failed, error: %lu", GetLastError());
            return NULL;
        }
        if (CryptStringToBinaryW(test, wcslen(test), CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW, buffer, &amount, NULL, NULL))
        {
            return buffer;
        }
    }
    printf("failed, error: %lu", GetLastError());
    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    LPCWSTR test = L"1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c";
    BYTE* first = NULL;
    DWORD amount = 0;
    first = ToBinary(test, first, amount);
    printf("%hS\n", first);
    printf("length is: %d\n", strlen(first));

    LPCWSTR test2 = L"686974207468652062756c6c277320657965";
    amount = 0;
    BYTE* second = NULL;
    second = ToBinary(test2, second, amount);
    printf("%hS\n", second);
    printf("length is: %d\n", strlen(second));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the actual wide string code that is not working for you, don't just describe it.

Comment: I added my code, the code works now but I'm not getting the expected amount of characters to properly xor the raw bytes.

Comment: You are not validating that `CryptStringToBinaryW()` reports `ERROR_MORE_DATA` when its `pbBinary` parameter is NULL, vs some other error. Also, if the second call to `CryptStringToBinaryW()` fails, you are leaking the allocated `buffer`. Also, why are you using `CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW` instead of `CRYPT_STRING_HEX`? And why are you using `CryptStringToBinaryW()` at all? Hex is very easy to parse manually, and a lot faster than using a system function.

Comment: ok, these are very questions which for most of them, I don't have any good valid answer which is why I will start fixing these issues right away but I still don't understand why the first input doesn't come back as it supposed to.

Comment: If I won't be able to solve it with the system API, I'll do it manually but it's strange for me why it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried this code but when I check the strlen of the first value,
>   it returns a length of 3 rather than 18 on the second hex string:

*The length of a C string is determined by the terminating null-character: A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character (without including the terminating null character itself).*

So the reason is the fourth character of `first` is a terminating null character (`'\0'`) cause `strlen` stop and return 3.